# Take the first characters

Tags: c#

I have this String: *Hello to all*.
 I want to take first 2 charcters from each word. The result: Hetoal. How can I do? I tried with a foreach

> foreach( string str in String)

but I received an error: *Cannot convert type char to String*

Comment: Your error is because when you enumerate through a string, you get `char` for each character, not string. So it should be `foreach(char c in String)`. But that's probably not what you wanted anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to split the sentence string into words, like this:

```
var sentence = "Hello to all.";
var words = sentence.Split(' ');
```

Then you can loop through each of the words in the sentence and grab the first two characters of each and append them to a result, like this:

```
string result;
var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(string word in words)
{
    // Get the first two characters if word has two characters
    if (word.Length >= 2)
    {
        resultBuilder.Append(word.Substring(0, 2));
    }
    else
    {
        // Append the whole word, because there are not two first characters to get
        resultBuilder.Append(word);
    }
}

result = resultBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: That assumes the string will have 2 characters in it. Instead of "2", you could use "Math.Min(2, word.Length)".

Answer (score 1):

Code example :

```
string someString = "Hello to all";
string[] words = someString.Split(' ');
string finalString = "";

foreach (string word in words) {
    finalString += word.Substring(0, 2);
}
// finalString = "Hetoal";
```

This splits the string into words and then foreach word it finds the first 2 characters and appends them to the `finalString` object.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution can be

```
string str = "Hello to all.";    
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in str.Split(' '))
{
   output.Append(s.Take(2));
}
string result = output.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string myString = "Hello to all";
var result = myString
             .Split(' ')
             .Select(x => x.Substring(0,Math.Min(x.Length,2)))
             .Aggregate((y,z) => y + z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

split your string around space

```
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word.Substring(0,2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some linq here:

```
string s = "Hello to all";
var words = s.Split(' ');
var result = new string(words.SelectMany(w=>w.Take(2)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String str = "Hello to all";
        String[] words = str.Split(' ');
        String completeWord = "";
        foreach (String word in words)
        {
            if(word.Length>1)
            completeWord+=word.Substring(0, 2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Hello to all";
string result = str.Split().Select(word => word.Substring(0, 2)).Aggregate((aggr, next) => aggr + next);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//original message  
string message = "hello to all";

//split into a string array using the space
var messageParts = message.Split(' ');

//The SelectMany here will select the first 2 characters of each
// array item. The String.Join will then concat them with an empty string ""
var result = String.Join("",messageParts.SelectMany(f=>f.Take(2)));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer's technical details.

Answer (score 0):

```
string word = "Hellow to all";   
string result = "";
foreach(var item in word.Take(2))
{
    result += item;
}
```

Comment: That results in "He". (And doesn't even compile the way it's written)

Comment: string result needed an intial value;